# How can I optimize this data table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So for a project, I have to create a database and attempt to optimize as much as possible. We are given text files with data listed and I'm having trouble figuring out how I can best relate these pieces.

For right now, I have a Persons data file with names, addresses, etc. and an Airport Data File with airport coordinates, address, etc. In the Airport data file, one of the values we are given is described as this:

```
PassengerFacilityFee - Fees charged by the airport per passenger per arrival.
```

Should I create a seperate table for the fees and then use foreign keys from `Persons` and `Airport`, or how else could I organize this?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I create a seperate table for the fees and then use foreign keys from Persons and Airport, or how else could I organize this?

No. The facility fee is purely a property of an airport. It is not related to specific people - there is not a different facility fee depending on whether Alice or Bob flies out of LAX, for instance. The fact that the fee is assessed "per passenger" is irrelevant here.

This fee should most likely be a column in your table of airport data.

Comment: This is what I was thinking initially, but wouldn't there be a "one to many" relationship from passengers to fees, since there could be more than 1 fee per passenger?

Comment: Maybe if you were trying to write some sort of accounting system? It's kind of hard to tell from your description. But as written, this fee is a property of an airport - it'd still exist even if there were no people in the system at all.

Comment: And there is no relationship between passengers and fees. The fee is used in a calculation that also uses the number of passengers in a flight. There is no relationship involved.